# How do I make my UI text centered to my 2d object when changing resolutions in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, 2d

I have a 2d circle in the scene, and a text inside it that I want to always be in the middle of the circle when I am changing resolutions.
For better understanding, it's just like a replica game.

Comment: More information can help with receiving answers. Are you using textmesh-pro or the default system? What is a replica game? Do you want the text to also retain sizing or merely position? What is the hierarchy of the objects you mentioned? Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: yes it's  default system.aa replica game is a game in which you shoot needles to a circular obstacle till you reach the target point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a circle including a text box. Make the text box child object of your circle and add `HorizontalLayoutGroup` to your circle

Tick all of its properties.